# Vuex and firebase: The user id is undefined in the firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am creating an e-commerce web site.

Now I finished creating the new account with email and password.

And I want to insert the user email, full name, and timestamp in the database.

As you can see in the picture below, I could see the USER data in the google chrome dev console.
[image]

But when I checked the firebase database in the browser, I cannot see the user id. And instead, I see undefined in the user id column.

[image]

Now I am on the step3 process.

3. Add user data into database

I cannot figure out why it's happening, so I hope you can help me out.

This is my store/index.js file.

```
import fireApp from '@/plugins/firebase'


export const state = () => ({
    
    user: null,
    error: null,
    busy: false,
    jobDone: false
})

export const mutations = {
   
    setUser (state, payload) {
        state.user = payload
    },
    setError (state, payload) {
        state.error = payload
    },
    clearError (state, payload) {
        state.error = null
    },
    setBusy (state, payload) {
        state.busy = payload
    },
    setJobDone (state, payload) {
        state.jobDone = payload
    },
}

export const actions = {
   
    signUpUser({commit}, payload) {
        commit('setBusy', true)
        commit('clearError')
        //1.Signup new user.
        //2.Update firebase user profile & set local user data.
        //3.Add user data into database
        //4.Attach user to consumer group
        let newUser = null
        fireApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
            .then(user => {
                newUser = user
                var user = fireApp.auth().currentUser;
                user.updateProfile({ displayName: payload.fullname })
                const currentUser = {
                    id: user.uid,
                    email: payload.email,
                    name: payload.fullname,
                    role: 'consumer'
                }
                console.log('USER', currentUser)
                commit('setUser', currentUser)
            })
            .then(() => {
                const userData = {
                    email: payload.email,
                    fullname: payload.fullname,
                    createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
                }
                
                fireApp.database().ref(`users/${newUser.uid}`).set(userData)
            })
            .then(() => {
                commit('setJobDone', true)
                commit('setBusy', false)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                commit('setBusy', false)
                commit('setError', error)
            })
    }
}

export const getters = {
    
    user (state) {
        return state.user
    },
    error (state) {
        return state.error
    },
    busy (state) {
        return state.busy
    },
    jobDone (state) {
        return state.jobDone
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the promise returned by [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword) method resolves with an [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#usercredential) object and not with a `User` one.

You should use the `user` property of the `UserCredential`, as follows:

```
    let newUser = null
    fireApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
        .then(userCredential => {
            newUser = userCredential.user;
            //...
```

---

Note also that you don't need to call `fireApp.auth().currentUser` to get the `user`.

When using the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method, on successful creation of the user account, this user will also be signed in to your application, so just get the user with `userCredential.user`, as explained above.

---

**In addition,** note that the [`updateProfile()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateprofile) method **is asynchronous** and returns a Promise, which you need to include in your promises chain.

So the following should do the trick (untested):

```
  signUpUser({commit}, payload) {
      commit('setBusy', true)
      commit('clearError')
      //1.Signup new user.
      //2.Update firebase user profile & set local user data.
      //3.Add user data into database
      //4.Attach user to consumer group
      let user = null;
      fireApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
          .then(userCredential => {
              user = userCredential.user;
              return user.updateProfile({ displayName: payload.fullname });
          })
          .then(() => {
              const currentUser = {
                  id: user.uid,
                  email: payload.email,
                  name: payload.fullname,
                  role: 'consumer'
              }
              console.log('USER', currentUser)
              commit('setUser', currentUser)
              const userData = {
                  email: payload.email,
                  fullname: payload.fullname,
                  createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
              }

              return fireApp.database().ref(`users/${user.uid}`).set(userData)
          })
          .then(() => {
              commit('setJobDone', true)
              commit('setBusy', false)
          })
          .catch(error => {
              commit('setBusy', false)
              commit('setError', error)
          })
  }
```

Comment: Very cool, thank you, I could make it. But I still have to keep calling fireApp.auth().currentUser because, I have the error "user is not defined. "  when I sign up.         Also your additional answer works! Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "when I sign up"? Within all the `then()` blocks after the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword in your code`, the user should be defined (since you don't signout). If you signout and re-signin then indeed you need to use `fireApp.auth().currentUser` or `onAuthStateChanged` to get the user.